# test the significance of clusters

Tags: clustering

Good morning, 
I am analyzing a dataset composed by 364 subjects and 13 binary variables (0,1 = absence,presence).
I am testing possible association (co-presence) of my variables. To do this, I was trying with cluster analysis.

My main interest is to check for the significance of the obtained clusters.

First, I tried with the `pvclust()` function, by using `method.hclust="ward"` and `method.dist="binary"`. Altoghether it works (clusters and significance obtained). However, I'm not convinced by the distance matrix. Association between variables are indeed different from results obtained in PAST by using Ward on a Jaccard matrix (that should be ok for binary data).
Moreover, when I try to obtain a Jaccard matrix in R from my data, by using the Vegan package

```
mydistance<-vegdist(t(data),method="jaccard")
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Error in rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

below an subset from my dataset:

```
variable1   variable2   variable3   variable4   variable5   variable6   variable7   variable8   variable9   variable10  variable11  variable12  variable13
case1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
case2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   NA  NA  1   0   0   0
case3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
case4   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
case5   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
case6   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
case7   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
case8   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
case9   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
case10  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
case11  1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
case12  0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
.....
```

So, my questions are the following: Is the Jaccard index a good strategy for my kind of data? Is binary distance used in pvclust is theoretically more correct? Is there any alternative to pvclust for testing the significance of my clusters?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: There is haze. 1) What are the clustering objects - variables or cases. 2) What is `significance` in your context? Also, 3) What is the `binary distance` - can you give the formula? 4) Jaccard is one popular measure for binary data, but there are dozens more. 5) Ward method is not recommended with binary data; why do you insist using Ward?

Comment: Thanks,I realize my questions were somewhat not clear, sorry. Pls consider that I'm relatively new to binary data. Regarding the points raised: I need to cluster variables, to check for their association (co-occurrence) in my dataset. I opted for the Jaccard (and the binary distance) for they do not consider joint non-occurrence. In my dataset, this is more suitable. About the Ward method, do you have any possible alternative, more appropriate for binary data?
About significance, I want to check the reliability of my clusters in consistently reflect an underlying association between variables.